# Database Capacity, Large Volume of Users

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, infrastructure

I'm working on a Back-end Application for a Nationwide Store. Currently I'm using mongodb

- How do I extend a particular database capacity, this purpose is to support a larger volume of users will be stored in my database in time. because It will be used by lots of users nationwide.
- Is there a Approach/Pattern or a feature technology must be apply to this matter?

Thanks

Comment: The subject of your question is so broad that people make whole careers out of doing that.  Get faster hardware, get a faster database, get faster disk, get faster network, cluster the database, design your queries more intelligently, cache data, and so on and so on.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hi, Yes I need this, in future transactions of our users, becoz our application will be used in nationwide, like ordering system

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You really ought to go read the posting rules for stack overflow.  This question is off-topic because it's way, way too broad.  Entire books are written and whole careers are pursued to do this.  This is not something that can be answered in a typical stack overflow answer.  That makes this question off-topic and inappropriate for stack overflow.  You can instead ask a much more specific question about how to speed up a particular query in mongodb or how to scale mongodb horizontally to increase compute resources or some other **much more specific** question.